# PhpOrient query returns negative Rid-s by default

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to retrieve a simple graph consisting of some Assignments that are linked to each other, however after querying one set of those assignments, the Rid-s that are returned are all negative and have nothing to do with the Rid-s in the database, so I can't run other query-s based on those Rid-s, how should I go around this, or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code snippet responsible:

```
$records = $this->client->queryAsync('select rID, value, schedule, priority, type from Assignment where type = 5');
foreach ($records as $record)
{
    $id = $record->getRid();
    $rid = $id->__toString();
    $return[$rid] = $this->client->query('TRAVERSE out("Assignment") FROM ' . $rid . ' WHILE $depth <= 5');
}
```

and the error that I receive:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#-2:0' was not found
```

However in the database the first id is: #18:0

Answer (score 1):

Hi Pirate's Lost Pearl,

is probably a problem with the transactions, orientdb makes negative RID-s when they are temporary. After the commit, the RID-s are changed to positive, here the [doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

First off you should change your `__toString();` into `_toString();` using a single underscore.

Then fix the `$this->client->query` by either switching quotation marks at the end such as `" WHILE $depth <= 5"` or concatenate the variable while keeping the same quotes `' WHILE ' . $depth . ' <= 5'`.

[OrientDB Docs | getRid()](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/PHP-Record-getRid.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but regardless the RiD-s were negative